# Lateral mean value dot in Bargraph.CI (see picture)

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add into a bargraph.CI a lateral that represents the mean value with error bars, like in the pictures. Any idea how?

[image]

How do I add this dot to the bargraph.CI? Thanks for the help